# RcppEigen svd is very slow

Tags: r, inline, eigen, rcpp, armadillo

Did RcppEigen's JacobiSVD become slower with upgrading to 3.0 ?
My library using RcppEigen is now working fast anymore.

```
> n<-1000
> m<-matrix(rnorm(n*n),n,n)

> unix.time(s1<-svd(m))       # R
   user  system elapsed 
 10.376   0.028  10.407 

> unix.time(s2<-svdArma(m))   # RcppArmadillo
   user  system elapsed 
 22.997   0.000  23.001 

> unix.time(s3<-svdEigen(m))  # RcppEigen
   user  system elapsed 
180.708   0.000 180.712
```

here is a test code on R :

```
library(inline)

codeArma='
    arma::mat    m = Rcpp::as<arma::mat>(m_);

    arma::mat u;
    arma::vec s;
    arma::mat v;

    arma::svd(u,s,v,m); 
    return List::create( Rcpp::Named("u")=u,
                         Rcpp::Named("d")=s,
                         Rcpp::Named("v")=v );
'
svdArma <- cxxfunction(signature(m_="matrix"),codeArma, plugin="RcppArmadillo")

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------

codeEigen='
  const Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd> m (as<Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd> >(m_ ));

  Eigen::JacobiSVD <Eigen::MatrixXd>svd(m,
                   Eigen::ComputeThinU|Eigen::ComputeThinV);
  return List::create( Rcpp::Named("u")=svd.matrixU(),
                       Rcpp::Named("d")=svd.singularValues(),
                       Rcpp::Named("v")=svd.matrixV() );
'
svdEigen <- cxxfunction(signature(m_="matrix"), codeEigen, plugin="RcppEigen")

#------------------------------------------------------------------------
n<-1000
m<-matrix(rnorm(n*n),n,n)

system.time(s1<-svd(m))       # R
m1<-s1$u %*% diag(s1$d) %*% t(s1$v)
all.equal(m,m1)

system.time(s2<-svdArma(m))   # Armadillo
m2<-s2$u %*% diag(array(s2$d)) %*% t(s2$v)
all.equal(m,m2)

system.time(s3<-svdEigen(m))  # Eigen
m3<-s3$u %*% diag(s3$d) %*% t(s3$v)
all.equal(m,m3)
```

## ----------------------------------------------------------

Comment: please do not mutilate the post like that. In general questions can be of value to others. The best thing to do would be for you to answer your own question. If you really feel there is no added value, you can simply delete it.

Comment: does the OP have permission to delete / flag for deletion at their current level of reputation (~80) ?

Answer (score 5):

Switching to R 3.0.0 should not per see have an impact on how a package such as `RcppEigen` performs.  If you saw a regression in performance, something else may be going on.

You can also try to ballpark things by compiling an SVD directly in C++ using Armadillo and / or Eigen (if you have them installed outside of R, and/or you may get the headers from the R packages used with some tinkering).